# Inverted Min Cost Max Flow

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, network-flow

I'm starting to think there's no possible solution to this problem, but before jumping to conclusions I want to confirm it with collective knowledge.
Let's imagine that there's a 2D grid, where S units need to go to T points, but the caveat is that going through a known/explored path has a lower cost than going through a new one (meaning, going through the same edges as other flows).

Max Flow Minimum Cost can easily handle exactly the opposite, meaning that it will prioritize to *spread* to cover as much ground as possible to reach the destinations. Still, this technique cannot be *inverted* to satisfy the original statement, meaning to reuse paths/cells to reach the destinations at a *lower* cost if the edge has any flow.

Comment: What does "S units need to go to T points" mean?  Each of the S units must be able to go to all of the T points?  Maybe S=T and you have a set of S pairs, where each pair describes the starting position of a unit and the desired ending position?  Apparently we are to find a set of paths, but what properties must that set of paths satisfy?

Comment: Depending on the problem formulation, you might be able to show it NP-hard by reduction from the (rectilinear) [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem) or the [minimum routing cost spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_routing_cost_spanning_tree).